# Can a C++ app or library be called from Node JS?

Tags: c++, node.js, process

Can a C++ app or library be called from Node JS? I want to use this PSD parser, https://molecular-matters.com/index.html on a node js express js server. The PSD Parser looks like an app rather than a library.

I'm on OSX 10.15.7

Comment: _"...Addons are dynamically-linked shared objects written in C++..."_ https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see inline-cpp for an easy-to-use interface:

const compile = require('inline-cpp');

```
const hello = compile `
  String func(const CallbackInfo& info) {
    return String::New(info.Env(), "Hello world from C++!");
  }
`

console.log(hello())
```

Downloads:

- my fork: https://github.com/lorros/node-inline-cpp
- original: https://www.npmjs.com/package/inline-cpp